# jQuery validation plugin continue error messaging

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am busy with some form validation and it is working but the messages keep on comming when you make a mistake.

So when you fill out in the emailfield with only a name the error comes but when you click again in that field the same message come up again.

How can i fix this that the message will be showing only one time? And when it's good that the message disappear?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/q7Z82/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `errorPlacement` option  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options. like this,

```
$("form.valid").validate({
    errorLabelContainer: "div.messages",
  //  errorElement: "div class='system error'",
    meta: "validate",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
          error.insertAfter(element);
   },
});
```

here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/q7Z82/2/

Comment: Jayantha, that is working yes. But when i use the errorElement tag (i dont want use labels but those divs) then its not working anymore?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the below:

```
$("form.valid").validate({
    errorLabelContainer: "div.messages",
    errorElement: "div class='system error'",
    meta: "validate",
    onkeyup: false,
    onclick: false
});
```

In terms of the message disappearing you could use any timeout you desired (say 1 second) and then have a call to the jQuery empty method.

```
setTimeout(function () { $("div.messages").empty() }, 1000)
```